# Conversion operator overloading with template

Tags: templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I want to be able to convert myclass to any base structures (double, int, float, etc). I used:

```
template<class T> myclass::operator T() {
    return (T)a;
};
```

But it gives me an error when I run it. But if I use:

```
myclass::operator double() {
    return (double)a;
};
```

(a is a private variable) the code works.

How can I use template in this situation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this to work at all, `a` must be convertible to `double`, `int`, and `float`.  Then your first example should work just fine.  I added extra enforcing by a `static_assert`.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

class myclass {
    double a = 1.0;
public:
    template<class T> operator T() {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<decltype(a),T>);
        return static_cast<T>(a);
    };
};

int main() {
    myclass m;

    int i = m;
    float f = m;
    double d = m;
  //std::string s = m; // BOOM!
}
```

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VDFUX8qMVO0noiMp)